# Determining the exit status of the "return" built-in

Tags: bash, shell, exit

I was reading about traps, but only return works for me in my shell script, so was wondering what status or code it returns, so what I tried is,

```
#!/bin/bash
seeOutput=`return`
echo $seeOutput
```

It's just returning a new line and when done on terminal, it says,

```
-bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
```

which I already know :p I just need to know "return"'s exit status.

Comment: `return` defaults to true. bash 4.3 has included `return -1` which means error. Thus `return` accept negative values as return value (e.g. return -1 will show as (8 bit) 255 in the caller). See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges

Comment: There's a good answer on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419952/difference-between-return-and-exit-in-bash-functions) for this question.

Comment: @val0x00ff, no, `return` defaults to `return "$?"` (that is, it returns with the exit status of the last run command).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas What I was meaning to say. Usually `return` on its own indicates true as you'd do in c  `return 0` to indicate success. Anything else will be false and ofcourse based on the status of `$?` returned from the last command. e.g `f(){ args=2; [[ $# = $args ]] && return  || return ; }; f 1`  Will hit the second `return`  which will be false.  However  `f(){ args=2; [[ $# = $args ]] && return  || return ; }; f 1 2` will hit the first `return` which will be true.

Comment: Since you know that you can only call `return` from a function or a sourced script, why are you calling it in another context? What do you expect to happen? And what do you mean by “ "return"'s exit status”? Since `return` causes its context to exit, there's no way to observe any exit status of the `return` instruction itself, what you observe is the exit status of the containing function or sourced script.

Comment: okay, but if I use 'exit 0' to get out of my script in some if/else clauses, instead of getting me at the prompt its logging me out! Hence I had to use return to do the same and it works well. I guess, I meant the value of '$?' by "return"'s exit status, the same way as every command is having this status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return code is stored in $? variable.

```
false ; echo $?
true ; echo $?
```

would return

```
1
0
```

unix convention is that 0 means OK.
in your exemple, seeOuput hold whatever output from the back quoted command.

Do not mistake output and return code.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is calling a shell command `return` which doesn't make sense.
In general, `return` with no value followed returns the exit status of the last command executed.

From `man`: Causes  a  function to exit with the return value specified by n.  If n is omitted, the return status is that of the last command executed in the function body.

Comment: But actually I was using return to just to get out of my script(If one of the command-line argument is missing) Thanks for adding this too to my knowledge! :)

Answer (score -1):

This is how I used it:

```
f()
{
   ls $AAA
   return $?
}

g()
{
   f
   return $?
}

d()
{
   g
   echo $?
}

AAA=
d
```

_

```
<contents of dir>
0
```

_

```
AAA=sdsasdasd
d
```

_

```
ls: sdsasdasd: No such file or directory
2
```